# How to find IP of the KVM Virtual Machine from Host system?

Tags: linux, kvm

My KVM VMs are connected using MaCVTAP connection VM network Interfaces. I have to manually go into the VM to find the IP address.
The VM interface doesn't ping to the host interface as the source device is MACVTAP.
Due to this arp -n would not show any IP information on the Host for any VMs.

Comment: Try [my solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33191/how-to-find-the-ip-address-of-a-kvm-virtual-machine-that-i-can-ssh-into-it/496834#496834) Will require virsh and qemu-guest agent